# AlertDialog closing during invoking of OnClickListener of adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have next code in my **DialogFragment**:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onCreateDialog");
    final FileSystemAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
    adapter.showFS(null);

    AlertDialog b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(title)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //some actions
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    adapter.showFS(adapter.getItem(i));
                }
            })
            .create();
    return b;
}
```

After clicking on element of list, last **onClick** method is invoking and then dialog is closing.

---

How to prevent this behavior and stay dialog opened until **dismiss** method called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a new ListView and set it as a custom view in AlertDialog.Builder and put your OnClickListener code into OnItemClickListener in listView. Try something like this:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int position, long itemId) {
         adapter.showFS(adapter.getItem(position));
    }
});

AlertDialog b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(title)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //some actions
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dismiss();
            }
        })
        .setView(listView)
        .create();
return b;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it 10 minutes before and it works. That's weird but so )